# Page gets displayed in post field

Tags: loop

I'm making my first WordPress theme from scratch, and I currently have two pages: `index`, and `events`. The `index` is static and the `events.php` is dynamic (loaded with latest events displayed by the title and thumbnail).

I also have two posts; one being the default Hello World, and the second made by me, some text and about 9 images.

The problem is when I try to run the loop, I only get one window with the title of the page:

```
get_header();            
/*
 Template Name: eventy
 */
?>        
<div id="innerContainer">
    <h2 style="color: #000c14">EVENTY</h2>
    <div id="GALERIA">                      
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
        <div class="gelement">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <div class="gimg"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                <div class="gtitle"> <p><?php the_title() ;?></p></div>
                        </a>
        </div><!--GELEMENT END-->     
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p>Sorry, no posts to list</p>
    <?php endif; ?>   
    </div><!--GLAERIA END -->
    <div id="zmianastrony">
        <p style="text-align: center; color: #000c14;">
            <a href="#" style="color: #000c14;">-Poprzednia</a>
            <a href="#" style="color: #000c14;">Następna-</a>
        </p>
    </div>  
</div> <!-- inner container END -->
<?php get_footer();
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to create a secondary archive/index page on the "events" template, but haven't modified the main query for the page. Without that, you will only get results for the one page. Try:

```
function events_wpse_206465($qry) {
  if (is_page('events') && is_main_query()) {
    $qry->set('posts_per_page',5);
    $qry->set('post_type','events');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','events_wpse_206465');
```

Or create a new query:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'events',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
);
$myq = new WP_Query($args);
if ($myq->have_posts()) {
    while ($myq->have_posts()) { 
        $myq->the_post();
        the_title(); 
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Found a different way, but this seems ok as well. Thanks

Comment: @aln447, would you please post your solution for the sake of others trying to solve a similar problem?

Comment: Your solution is virtually identical to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by placing this on the top:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query ( array(
  'category_name' => 'eventsy'
  ))?>          
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```